# VMMap v3.32 does not analyze Managed Heap on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: heap-memory, managed, vmmap

[Managed Heap tab is not populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpwJF.png)

The VMMap utility does not show the memory details of the Managed heap. Have tried to run it on both Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012R2. Any inputs on how to make it work will be helpful ? Have seen similar questions on the web but no one has answered the solution.

Comment: Same issue here, in windows 11pro - version 10.0.22000. This seems like long pending issue without an solution or workaround. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Just ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run your programm by hand.
2. Run VMMap and select it from "View a running process" tab.

I suppose it links somehow to rights.

Comment: Look at screenshot from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap. Managed heap is empty:)